# How to pronounce $\breve{E}$?

Tags: pronunciation

**How to pronounce $\breve{E}$ ?**

The TeX command for it is "\breve{E}" , but I don't know if it would be correct to say "E breve" during a presentation.

Comment: Just say E-hat.

Comment: But E-hat is $\hat{E}$.

Comment: I think it's " E tilde" .

Comment: I personnally say $E-$check, but here are lots of ways : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caron This is a Czech symbol, and this is not the same as the Spanish tilde

Comment: It's "E-háček", see https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/h%C3%A1%C4%8Dek – if you pronounce it "E-hatcheck", you won't be far off.

Comment: tilde would rather be $\widetilde E$ @asma

Comment: @GerryMyerson: No, it's rounded, not pointy! See https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/breve.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe: This is not Czech. See my comment to Gerry Myerson above.

Comment: OK, breve it is: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breve